# Task Scheduler only runing part of a batch script

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I have a script that checks the status of a service and then depending on if it's missing, running, or stopped it will take an action and write to log.

this works perfectly when running manually but when attempting to run it in task scheduler only the first section of the script runs. I'm still new to batch scripting so not entirely sure how to find where or why it's not running fully and why only in task scheduler.

I've attempted running the script under different users, as well as SYSTEM, and LOCAL SERVICE all with the same result I've also checked and set permissions to allow everything for everyone. i can only assume it's something in the code that is causing it to not run completely.

```
@echo off
SET DIR=C:\Program Files\My Program\Temp
SC QUERY MYSERVICE > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1060 GOTO :MISSING
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('SC QUERY MYSERVICE ^| findstr "        STATE"') do echo %%H > "%DIR%\ServiceState.txt"
set /p status= <ServiceState.txt
IF %status% == RUNNING GOTO :RUNNING
IF %status% == STOPPED GOTO :STOPPED
GOTO :EOF
```

**running in Task Scheduler the script stops at this point as ServiceState.txt gets created but ServiceLog.txt does not**

```
:STOPPED
ECHO "%date% %time% Service Stopped" >> "%DIR%\ServiceLog.txt"
Net Start MYSERVICE >>  "%DIR%\ServiceLog.txt"
GOTO :EOF


:RUNNING
ECHO "%date% %time% Service Running" >> "%DIR%\ServiceLog.txt"
GOTO :EOF


:MISSING
ECHO "%date% %time% Service Missing" >> "%DIR%\ServiceLog.txt"
CALL "C:\Program Files\My Program\Temp\MYSERVICE-ServiceUninstall.bat"
CALL "C:\Program Files\My Program\Temp\MYSERVICE-ServiceInstall.bat"
ECHO "%date% %time% Service Reinstalled" >> "%DIR%\ServiceLog.txt"
Net Start MYSERVICE >> "%DIR%\ServiceLog.txt"
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: "_all with the same result_"... is that the same as the working result, or the same as the non-working result? Also, where exactly does it get to when run from the task scheduler? Add some more `ECHO` statements so you can see exactly where. Finally, in `set /p status= <ServiceState.txt` should the filename have a `%DIR%` prefix and be wrapped in double-quotes?

Comment: Running as different users in Task Scheduler still results in only part of the script executing. Above code edited to show where it stops at. I'll try the double quotes, Thanks

Comment: Remember to add the directory as well, e.g. `set /p status= <"%DIR%\ServiceState.txt"`. My guess is that line is failing because it cannot find the file as input. Also, to be pedantic (as one needs to be when debugging), you still don't know _exactly_ where the script stops. The place you've indicated is `GOTO :EOF`, which is the end of the script anyway! Even if my suggestion fixes things, as an exercise for the future, add lines of the form `echo %TIME% Step1>>"%DIR%\trace.txt"` around _all_ lines in the first snippet so you can see exactly what's happening.

Comment: Adding the %DIR% fixed it.  Missed that in all my proof reads, thanks! looks like when Task scheduler would run it it would fail to set %status% and just goto :eof
thanks for the debugging tips :)

Comment: The `set/p` will be ending with the `set /p` line because it throws an error (file not found). Until you get that you can spot such things easily (and it's never as easy for you looking at your own code as it is when looking at someone else's), I urge you to practice in the future adding debugging `ECHO`s. You needn't start with _every_ line: add them at "key places" (e.g. before calling `SC`, before reading the status, before doing the conditional jumps) so you can narrow down where the problem lies.

Comment: And, as a freebie, you can probably dispense with writing and reading the status (unless you _want_ that in a file) by replacing `do echo %%H > ...` with `do set "status=%%H"` and removing the `set/p` line.

Comment: perfect thanks! I was having issues do a ```Set Status=%%H``` on the next line so i just wrote it to disk and read it back in.